Decision Tree Regressor Output
I have a very simple dataset of employee age and years of experience as features and income as label. The ask is to predict the income level using various regressors and I am using 4: Decision Trees (DT), Random Forest (RF), K-Nearest Neighbor (KNN) and Linear Regression (LR). The following table gives the income level as predicted by each of the 4 regressors.
My questions are:

Why is DT predicting such tight income levels, (almost equal to the actual income of the data set) while other regressors seem to be working fine? Is it because the data is too small for the DT to train / the number of features too low (only 2 features) or is it something else?
How come DT gives absurd results but RF does not?
The R^2 and MSE for DT is less than and more than that for LR, respectively, but still, DT seems to be producing more tighter range. How?



Not including any code here as this is more of a contextual question. Can provide code if needed.


Decision Trees work best when the dataset is large and there are multiple features. If the dataset is small and the features are limited, Decision Tree Overfits the data. Regularization, Cross-Validation, Data Augmentation, Feature Engineering, pruning, Hyperparameter tuning,  Normalization can help generate good results using Decision Trees.
Random Forest reduces variance and generates generalizable predictions, as a result of averaging multiple trees.
The piecewise constant predictions in DT can be precise in each region but overall, while generalizing it might not perform good in addition to overfitting.

